# Keyboard not being dismissed before alertview

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I have a form, there are two fields, one is a text input, the other triggers a date picker to appear.

When editing the text field, the keyboard is on screen, when I press to display the date picker in the field below the keyboard remains on screen despite my attempts to suppress it.

**TL;DR**

```
 self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Isn't dismissing the keyboard

```
@IBAction func actDroppedOff(_ sender: Any) {
    dismissKeyboard()

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    DatePickerDialog().show("Select Picked Up Date", doneButtonTitle: "Finished", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", datePickerMode: .date) {
        (date) -> Void in
        if let dt = date {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "MM'-'dd'-'yyyy"
            self.txtDroppedOff.text = formatter.string(from: dt)

        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can call textfield.resignFirstResponder() to dismiss keyboard to

Answer (score 0):

`self.view.endEditing(true)` should dismiss the keyboard for you. I'm not sure why you are calling `dismissKeyboard()` before that? What's in that function?

Comment: Can ignore that, that's a method that does basically the same thing. I've tried with/without.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using textfields. In this case, try the following: `func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }`